# Ampersand in PlaceHolder of scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

What will be the output of the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n;

int main() {
    scanf("&d", &n);

    switch (n) {
      case 1:
        printf("hello\n");
        break;
      case 2:
        printf("good\n");
        break;
      default:
        printf("Morning\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Most people expected there to be an error but on execution it always outputs `Morning` no matter what input is given.

Comment: What do think an error looks like?

Comment: Initialise `int n=1;` and see what happens.

Comment: The question was whether it would give a runtime error,  or show morning all the time?

Comment: Then change and init to 2 instead and see what happens.

Comment: Try `default: printf("%i\n", n);`

Comment: Your code doesn't need `n` as a global variable, but it is (un)fortunate for you that using a global means it is initialized to zero by default, so the fact that the `scanf()` does nothing to it doesn't matter — you aren't running into undefined behaviour.  But, in future and in general, avoid both global variables and uninitialized variables.

Comment: @jonathan leffer this question was on a test paper of introduction to CS course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output will always be `Morning`.

`scanf("&d")` expects as input the two characters `&` and `d`, literally. If you type anything else, the `scanf` call will fail. However, your code doesn't check the return value of `scanf`, so it makes no difference.

The `&n` argument to `scanf` is ignored because there is no "conversion specification" (those are the things starting with `%`) in the format string. Thus (as the C standard says (C99, 7.19.6.2 *The `fscanf` function* / 2)):

> If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess
>   arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.

`scanf("&d", &n)` is therefore equivalent to just `scanf("&d")`.

When `switch (n)` examines `n`, it will still contain the value it was initialized with. There is no explicit initializer, so it is set to `0` (because it's a global variable (specifically, because it has static storage; see C99, 6.7.8 *Initialization* / 10)).

There is no `case 0:` label, so `default:` kicks in.

Comment: I was looking exactly for the quote but did not find it. Could you cite precisely please?

Comment: @Yunnosch Added some citations.

Comment: Thanks. The answer was already good anyway of course. Just for the wanna-be language lawyers.... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

"Morning" is the correct output for this program.

In the first place, there is no reason to expect an error message, because the program does not anywhere print one.  In particular, C standard library functions such as `scanf()` do not emit error messages to the standard streams.  Instead, they return status information via their *return values*, and in some cases by setting the thread-local variable `errno`.  This program does not even check the return value of `scanf`, so there is no reason to think that it will emit an error message on account of any problem there.

Secondly, although the format string passed to `scanf` appears to contain a typo, it is still a perfectly valid format.  It tells `scanf` to attempt to read (but do nothing else with) the two-character sequence "&d".  If those are not the next two characters it sees, then it will fail with a matching error, which it will indicate by returning 0.  In fact, it will *also* return 0 if those are the next two characters, because the return value communicates the number of *input fields* successfully scanned, converted, and stored, and the format does not describe any input fields.

The second `scanf` argument is ignored in all cases, but some compilers will emit a warning (not an error) about it.

Since `scanf` does not assign a value to variable `n`, it retains whatever value it had before the call.  Since it was declared at file scope, it is automatically initialized to zero before the start of the program, and it still has this value when exectution reaches the `switch` statement.  This results in the default case being exercised.